# Вывести сколько и каких знаков препинания содержится в строке символов

Tags: c, строки, символы

Строка символов до точки, подсчитать, сколько и каких знаков препинания она содержит.
Написал такой код. Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить код (на Си) на switch case и заменить все переменные хранящие количество каждого символа на массив, чтобы не было столько переменных. Буду очень признателен, если поможете исправить.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str_in[30];
    int i=0, dot=0, zap=0, dv=0, vos=0, vop=0, tir=0, dz=0;
    gets(str_in);
    for(;str_in[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        if(str_in[i]=='.')
            {
                dot++;
                break;
            }
        if(str_in[i]==',')
            zap++;
        if(str_in[i]==':')
            dv++;
        if(str_in[i]=='!')
            vos++;
        if(str_in[i]=='?')
            vop++;
        if(str_in[i]=='-')
            tir++;
        if(str_in[i]==';')
            dz++;
    }
    printf(".=%d ,=%d :=%d !=%d ?=%d -=%d ;=%d\n", dot, zap, dv, vos, vop, tir, dz);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно и короче:

```
int main()
{
    char str_in[30];
    const char punct[] = ".,:!?-;";
    int pcount[sizeof(punct)/sizeof(punct[0])] = {0};
    gets_s(str_in,30);  // или fgets(str_in,30,stdin); в зависимости от компилятора
    for(int i = 0;str_in[i];i++)
    {
        const char * c = strchr(punct,str_in[i]);
        if (c) pcount[c-punct]++;
    }
    for(int i = 0;punct[i];i++)
        printf("%c : %d\n",punct[i],pcount[i]);
}
```

См. https://ideone.com/vagZoT

Самое приятное — для расширения списка символов пунктуации не нужно ничего, кроме как добавить новый символ в строку `punct`...

Comment: Плюсую - хороший код. И мне кажется, что по быстродействию поиск по массиву не уступит перебору по `switch`.

Comment: Благодарю, подскажите, как исправить ваш код, чтобы он считал до первой точки(включительно), т.е. после первой точки завершался и дальше не считал?

Comment: Добавьте в цикл проверку - `if (c=='.') break;` - после строки с увеличением `pcount[]`.

Comment: Попробовал, не работает

Comment: А, да, немного не так написал. Но и вы могли бы подумать немного, а не на готовенькое.... https://ideone.com/pxcQT2

Answer (score 1):

- определяешь константы для индексов знаков препинания в массиве
- создаешь *проинициализированный* массив для подсчета частот знаков препинания
- переписываешь условие выхода из цикла -- пока не обнаружена точка, так как в `case` отработает свой `break`, чтобы избежать ненужного `goto`
- переписываешь вывод результатов

Также лучше заменить вызов небезопасной функции `gets` на более приличную `fgets`, в которую следует также передать допустимый размер строки ввода.

Вариант решения:

```c
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {
    const int DOT = 0, COMMA = 1, COLON = 2, EXCL = 3, QUEST = 4, DASH = 5, SEMI = 6;
    char str_in[30];
    short stats[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    fgets(str_in, sizeof(str_in), stdin);
    for (int i = 0; str_in[i] != '\0' && stats[DOT] == 0; i++) {
        switch (str_in[i]) {
            case '.': stats[DOT]++;   break;
            case ',': stats[COMMA]++; break;
            case ':': stats[COLON]++; break;
            case '!': stats[EXCL]++;  break;
            case '?': stats[QUEST]++; break;
            case '-': stats[DASH]++;  break;
            case ';': stats[SEMI]++;  break;
        }
    }
    printf(".=%d ,=%d :=%d !=%d ?=%d -=%d ;=%d\n", 
        stats[DOT], stats[COMMA], stats[COLON], stats[EXCL], 
        stats[QUEST], stats[DASH], stats[SEMI]
    );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А еще лучше сделать 2 массива размером с самый большой код знака препинания + 1. В первом (его можно сделать битовым, но лучше (быстрее) char) отметить элементы, соответствующими знакам препинания, а второй обнулить. Тогда для каждого символа, используя его код как индекс, можно проверить (в первом массиве), что он является знаком препинания и увеличить соответствующий элемент во втором массиве.

Comment: Да, такая хэш-таблица на минималках получится :)